# How to specify JRE System Library for ALL Java Projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

Context: University Student learning Java by working in Eclipse **Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0) Build id: 20230907-1323.**

Ever since I have reinstalled Eclipse due to a PC Reset eclipse started showing me SuperClass Constructor errors and I couldnt wrap my head around why it happened. I had properly installed Java SE 21, added the path in Environment Variables and had started working on University Coding exercises as usual. But then the errors kept popping up and upon looking at Stackoverflow I found that I had to specify a JRE System Library for that project and I would be done with it because it had some Unbound error. Did that, it worked. But now I have to do that every time I import a new project...

My question is: Can I make so that it knows my JRE System Library (JDK-21) by default and not having to do that extra step every time?

Tried to Import a Project

Expected Project to work Normally

Project has Build Path Issues